# How to communicate between two Weblogic domains?

Tags: java, security, cross-domain, weblogic

I have an application deployed on a Weblogic domain which gets a request from the browser for login.

The actual login process occurs on a SECOND Weblogic domain which resides on the same machine.

I need the following:
 - Identify on the first domain that a call was made for login.
 - Forward the login request to the second domain.
 - Send the response from the second domain to the first one so it will continue the process; e.g. if the user was authenticated successfully, then need to open a session for him, return a response to the browser etc.

**NOTES**
 - I assume that I should use filter in web.xml for identifying that a login request has arrived and if I'm right I would like to hear how it connects to the call to the second server.
 - I'm interested in how to implement the communication between the 2 domains.
 - How would you prevent fake "successful authentication" calls to the first domain; i.e. I want to make sure that if my first domain got a successful authentication call then I want to be sure that the call indeed passed through the authentication server, (i.e. the second domain).

I would appreciate any idea or help on this, Thanks !!!

Comment: What do you mean by " login process occurs on a SECOND Weblogic "? Do you have an application running on the second domain for user valadation?

Comment: @Harry.Chan Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Currently I used a filter in the first application (= first Weblogic domain), that filters a login request and passes the request to the second application (= second Weblogic domain), which was exposed as a web service. Do you recommend another way for this communication? As I asked above, is there a way to identify fake "successful authentication" calls to the first domain? Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Well,I have two ideas,just for your own consideration!

First,just use digital certificate to sign the request,for webserivce https is the option,this is the common way to deal with fabrication problem.

Second,Implement your custom security provider is a more standard way than do it in the filter,it's typcially a JAAS LoginModule implementation,which call the webservice on the second domain for authentication.By this way ,authentication is delegated to weblogic server and the application for on first domain has loosely coupled with the second domain.

By the way, check the weblogic documentation for detail of  how to implement a custom provider,this is for weblogic version 10.3.2
[Developing Security Providers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13718/toc.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea; I'll read about developing security providers.